How to correctly link the libomp dynamic library in Xcode?
I am writing an OpenMP C program (it can simply be a omp_set_num_threads(x) instruction). I can build and execute it in terminal with the command clang -Xclang -fopenmp -L/opt/homebrew/opt/libomp/lib -I/opt/homebrew/opt/libomp/include -lomp main.c.
What I want to do is to compile and run in the same way in Xcode. So, I have done the following.
In "Build Settings" of my "Target", I've added:

"Other C Flags" items: -Xclang and -fopenmp
"Header Search Paths" item: /opt/homebrew/opt/libomp/include
"Library Search Paths" item: /opt/homebrew/opt/libomp/lib
"Other Linker Flags" item: -lomp

Build is successful, but when the program runs it stops in debug mode giving a new tab called "0 __abort_with_payload", containing:
dyld`__abort_with_payload:
    0x19ec54620 <+0>:  mov    x16, #0x209               ; =521 
    0x19ec54624 <+4>:  svc    #0x80
->  0x19ec54628 <+8>:  b.lo   0x19ec54648               ; <+40>         Thread 1: signal SIGABRT
    0x19ec5462c <+12>: pacibsp 
    0x19ec54630 <+16>: stp    x29, x30, [sp, #-0x10]!
    0x19ec54634 <+20>: mov    x29, sp
    0x19ec54638 <+24>: bl     0x19ebece60               ; cerror_nocancel
    0x19ec5463c <+28>: mov    sp, x29
    0x19ec54640 <+32>: ldp    x29, x30, [sp], #0x10
    0x19ec54644 <+36>: retab  
    0x19ec54648 <+40>: ret    

Then, instead of the -lomp value in "Other Linker Flags" I also tried to enter:

the static library path: /opt/homebrew/opt/libomp/lib/libomp.a. The application is built and runs successfully.
the dynamic library path: /opt/homebrew/opt/libomp/lib/libomp.dylib. The behavior is the same as when I entered -lomp.

How can I correctly set the dynamic library?

Check ldd a.out or however you named your application. Can the dynamic linker find the libomp library? You would either need to extend DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH to include the directory that contains libomp. Alternatively, you might add the directory into the rpath of the application by adding -Wl,--rpath,/opt/homebrew/opt/libomp/lib/

@Joachim I executed tool -L main and it displayed "/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1351.0.0)".
Could you please go deeper on the two solutions you provided (for the first one, at the moment, I have not any DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable if I execute printenv)?

@Joachim I've set the DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH into my target -> Edit Scheme -> Run -> Arguments -> Environment Variables. But nothing.
I've also tried in combination with -lomp (did you mean I had to remove -lomp or not?).
Regarding the second solution, I can't understand how to set that long option (in which field of "Build Settings"? In a separated way?).

I finally caught it.
One can freely load the dynamic library as I described in my question. When it comes to the 0 __abort_with_payload point, the issue is solved by not having neither "App Sandbox" nor "Hardened Runtime" in the project settings (select .xcodeproj file) under "Signing and Capabilities".
The same can be achieved by having a <projectname>.entitlements file.
Indeed, "Hardened Runtime" is set by default in Xcode projects.
If one wants to preserve the default Hardened Runtime, he can write the <projectname>.entitlements file as:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.security.cs.allow-dyld-environment-variables</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.cs.disable-library-validation</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>

